# Capture Exception raised when Gunicorn worker exiting

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I have a flask application, with Gunicorn acting as WSGI. Also, I am capturing application logs in Stackdriver Logging

When a gunicorn worker exits, it doesnt send any logs to the Stackdriver and worker is just killed.

I would like the worker to send one final logs to Stackdriver logger before exiting the application

Adjusting timeout parameter may help in worker not exiting... but I would like to know how to handle worker getting killed scenario

Here is the command I used to start Flask App

```
gunicorn -c  config/gunicorn.py --worker-class=gthread --timeout 5 "main:create_app()"
```

I would like to capture the log and send it to Stackdriver, when the app exits

Comment: Have you tried server hooks? http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#server-hooks on_exit or worker_exit might work for your needs.